# I deleted a shortcut on my dekstop and the same shortcut/files got deleted on other user dekstop (windows 10)

Tags: windows, file, window, shortcut-file

so the problem is just like what on the title. This has never been a problem before, i could delete what's on my dekstop and it just delete the file on my dekstop. But today as the title says i deleted a shortcut on my dekstop and the shortcut also got deleted on other user on that computer. This works vice versa, i already checked so when he deleted a shortcut it happens to my dekstop too. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desktop is a combined view of the files in your desktop folder and the `c:\users\Public\Desktop` folder.

Programs that are installed for all users might put their shortcut in the shared Public folder...